# Symfony 3 dateType add default option

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-3.2

This is what I have:

- One select field with months
- One select field with years

But in the month select field I would like to add an default option like:

```
<option value="current">Current</option>
```

I have no idea how to add the default option, an placeholder is no option.
This is my code right now, using a dateType

```
->add('startDate', DateType::class, [
    'label' => 'Start date',
    'label_attr' => array('class' => 'sr-only'),
    'placeholder' => [
        'year' => 'Year',
        'month' => 'Month',
    ],
    'years' => range(date('Y')-70, date('Y')),
])
```

Who can help me with this?
Thanks!

Comment: Post the controller action you use that type with. In short: Just set the value in the entity (either in the constructor or in the controller action that generates this form).

Comment: Might be just as easy to do this outside of symfony, like in jQuery. Just add a link next to the form that says "Current date", then onClick set the Year and Month select fields accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

To set default value use `, array('data' => new \DateTime())`

```
->add('startDate', DateType::class, [
    'label' => 'Start date',
    'label_attr' => array('class' => 'sr-only'),
    'placeholder' => [
       'year' => 'Year',
       'month' => 'Month',
       ],
    'years' => range(date('Y')-70, date('Y')),
    'data' => new \DateTime(),
])
```

Answer (score 0):

`range` is used to generate an array, so the easiest way to do that, would be just add your value at the begining of the array.

Something like:

`'years' => array_merge(['current'=>'current'], range(date('Y')-70, date('Y')))`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately it wont work because I need to add the default option to my 'month' select.

Comment: By adding a range on the month ('months' => array_merge(['current'=>'current'], range(date('m'), 12)),)

Warning: gmmktime() expects parameter 4 to be integer, string given

Comment: I think i misunderstood what you wanted then. Do you want to add an option with the 'current' (string) value and text ? Or do you want to have the current month `selected="selected"` by default ?

Comment: I want to add an option 'current' value and text (string). Maybe I have to use the ChoiceType instead of the DateType?

Comment: Based on the error you had before with `gmmktime()`, that would be my guess too. `DateType` is running all the years in `gmmktime()` so that he can then run them through the `TimeFormatter` to match whatever `format` you choose. `ChoiceType` will accept anything, but also means that you have to ensure the validity of the data (that it's indeed a date) yourself. For me selecting the current year as default seems like a better option.